# Equivariant handle decompositions

Tags: smooth-manifolds, gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology, morse-theory, equivariant

Suppose I have some smooth closed **high-dimensional** manifold $M$ acted on smoothly by a **finite** group $G$.  By a metric averaging procedure, we can equip $M$ with a smooth Riemannian metric so that $G$ acts by isometries.  I can't necessarily pick a $G$-invariant morse function $f:M\to\mathbb R$, but nevertheless, I can certainly pick a smooth function $f:M\to\mathbb R$ which, though perhaps not Morse, still has only isolated "nice" critical points in some precise sense.  We therefore conclude:

> There is a "handle" decomposition of $M$ (where I haven't said what I mean by "handle") which is preserved by $G$.  Thus $G$ just permutes (and/or acts on individually) the handles.

I am interested in knowing to what extent this can be generalized to the case of an "action up to homotopy".  More specifically, suppose we have $G\to\operatorname{Homeo}(M)/\text{homotopy}$.  To what extent can we "decompose" M into simple pieces in a $G$-invariant way?  If it helps, then it is OK to assume that the action of $G$ is "close to the identity" in a vague coarse sense.

(I am essentially just interested on the case of high-dimensional $M$, but of course the question makes sense in any dimension).

Comment: This does not answer your question, but provides a different approach to the Morse theory in the first part.  A theorem of Illman says that if $M$ is a manifold and $G$ is a finite group acting on $M$, then $M$ has a $G$-invariant triangulation.  You could get an equivariant handle decomposition from this, but it is in some sense more rigid.  See MR1770606 (2001j:57032) Illman, Sören(FIN-HELS) Existence and uniqueness of equivariant triangulations of smooth proper G-manifolds with some applications to equivariant Whitehead torsion. J. Reine Angew. Math. 524 (2000), 129–183.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the meaning of "$G\to\operatorname{Homeo}(M)/\text{homotopy}.$"   ?

Comment: Say that two elements of $\operatorname{Homeo}(M)$ are equivalent iff they are homotopic as maps $M\to M$.  This is an equivalence relation, and the group operation on $\operatorname{Homeo}(M)$ descends to the quotient.

Comment: @JohnPardon do you mean "two maps of $Homeo(M)$ are equivalent iff they are homotopic _through homeomorphisms_ as maps $M \to M$? Because otherwise it's not clear that the inverses of equivalent maps are equivalent.

Comment: When $M=S^n$ is a sphere, then the space of orientation preserving homeomorphism is arc connected. In this case $G \to \textrm{Homeo}^+(M)/\textrm{homotopy} = pt$ seems to be no data at all? Is that really what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

This foundational paper: Arthur G. Wasserman, Equivariant Differential Topology, *Topology*, 8(1967), 127-150, has section 4 dealing with equivariant Morse theory for manifolds with a smooth action of a compact Lie group, including equivariant handle attaching, equivariant Morse Lemma, etc. See [MathSciNet Review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=250324). The last result of the paper concludes that a compact *G*-manifold is a union of "handle bundles over orbits".

Comment: This is a good reference for my boxed statement, but that's not what my question is about.  I want to know about when the action is only defined "up to homotopy".  Also, all my groups are finite.

Comment: I'm upvoting because if somebody googles "equivariant handle decompositions" (which is, after all, the title of the question), they will be well-served to find this answer. Perhaps it's worth mentioning that an equivariant handle consists of an equivariant disc bundle over a homogenous space $G/H$.